# perl modifying hash in sub

Tags: perl, pointers, reference, hashtable

I'm having trouble understanding how references work with hashes in subs.

In this code, I try to change `%config` inside the `handleOptions()` subroutine :

```
sub handleOption;

my %config = (  gpg => "",
                output => "",
                pass => "",
                host => "",
                type => "");

handleOptions(\%config);
print "\n";
print Dumper \%config;

sub handleOptions
{
    my ($gpgpath,$type,$pass,$host);
    my $pConfig=@_;

    GetOptions ("gpg=s" => \$gpgpath,
                "type=s" => \$type,
                "host=s" => \$type,
                "pass=s"=>\$pass);
    $pConfig->{'gpg'} = $gpgpath;
    $pConfig->{'type'} = $type;
    $pConfig->{'pass'} = $pass;
    $pConfig->{'host'} = $host;
    print Dumper %$pConfig;
}
```

Here is the output when I give `--gpg='/home/daryl/gpg/pass.gpg` to the options in cli :

```
$VAR1 = 'pass';
$VAR2 = undef;
$VAR3 = 'gpg';
$VAR4 = '/home/daryl/gpg/pass.gpg';
$VAR5 = 'type';
$VAR6 = undef;
$VAR7 = 'host';
$VAR8 = undef;

$VAR1 = {
          'pass' => '',
          'gpg' => '',
          'type' => '',
          'output' => '',
          'host' => ''
        };
```

How should i proceed ?

Comment: Try this: `my ($pConfig) = @_;`

Comment: Perfect demonstration of the value of always using strict and warnings.

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` won't help him with the subroutine declaration mismatch, though.

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;` in your perl code.
And when passing arguments to a function ,receive in this manner `my($arg1, $arg2, @garbage) = @_;`

Comment: @TLP by "subroutine declaration mismatch" I was referring to the `sub handleOption;` declaration not matching the name of the subroutine itself.

Comment: @smithfarm Ah, you mean that the pre-declaration `sub handleOption` does not match the subroutine main declaration `sub handleOptions`, because the latter has an "s" at the end of it. True, but then again, that part is invisible for all intents and purposes.

Comment: thank you too for that i did not see it x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were to `use strict` and `use warnings`, you'd see an error message about using a scalar as a hash reference. That would tip you off that the problem is in this line:

```
my $pConfig=@_;
```

You're assigning a scalar context of the array `@_` to the variable `$pConfig`. What this means is that `$pConfig` is storing the number of elements in the array `@_`.

Instead, you can do:

`my ($pConfig) = @_;` as KerrekSB suggests, or:

`my $pConfig = shift;` (which `shift`s from `@_` automatically)

Take a look at [`perldoc perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) for more information on calling non-scalars in scalar context. Also, unless you're writing a one-liner or a short throw-away script, make sure to always `use strict` and `use warnings`.

Comment: Thank you very much to you all that solved my problem :)I'm really new to perl, i still often forget to set these "strict/warnings" lines

Comment: @Azryel - You're welcome. I'd recommend picking up a copy of [Learning Perl](http://www.amazon.com/Learning-Perl-Randal-L-Schwartz/dp/1449303587) for a relatively light read that will get you up and running, and/or [Programming Perl](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Perl-Unmatched-processing-scripting/dp/0596004923/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1358441774&sr=1-1&keywords=programming+perl) which is a much thicker book, but is more comprehensive.